# Using Daydream Emulator in Unity with one phone only

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, daydream

My Daydream controller battery died and I would like to continue my tests by using my Android device as the emulator.

The [Daydream guide](https://developers.google.com/vr/daydream/controller-emulator) requires having 2 Android phones (headset phone, emulator phone) to be able to use a phone emulator. However considering Unity' Game View functionality provides the functionality of the headset phone I think simply one Android phone could be used as the emulator.

So I tried using the Instant Preview as Controller Only and opening the Emulator however Emulator remains as "Waiting for connection". Any official solutions to this or any workarounds?

GVR SDK: v1.130.1
Android Studio 3.0.1
Java jdk1.8.0_162.jdk
Pixel 2 phone
MacBook High Sierra

Comment: If daydream controller battery is dead, recharge it.....

Comment: it is not. also according to the official guide I shared it is not supported anyway?

Comment: *"My daydream controller battery died and I would like to continue my tests by using my Android device as the emulator."* That's what I was replying to

Comment: ah right:) When I charge it dies again in a couple of mins. Regardless of that looking to find a way to use the emulator with one phone (without a spare phone)

Comment: Not sure if there is another way. Just get a new battery and safe your time looking for alternate solution

Comment: it actually worked back properly after 24 hours of charging. it looked like charged after 1-2 hours with light turning constant but apparently it wasn't charged. Still though I think it would be a useful functionality - created this as an issue for GVR on github (not sure if there is a better way to request features)

Comment: Using GitHub is fine if software problem otherwise contact the marker directly if hardware problem

Comment: I doubted what to do as it is rather a feature request, not a bug. they responded though, thanks